# AFNetworking pin public key for a trusted certificate

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I use AFNetworking 2.3.1, I have a trusted certificate for which I'd like to pin the public key.

I have the `crt`, `key`, `pfx` files, so I imagine I have to add them into my bundle.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
    initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation,
        id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    return [self processError:[operation response]];
}];
[operation start];
```

Now how can I tell AFNetworking to use the `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` mode ?
(I don't see the `setSSLPinningMode` method from `AFHTTPRequestOperation`)

And how do I tell AFNetworking to use the added key ? I can't find any example on the documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AFNetworking has an AFSecurityPolicy object has values for security features, including the SSL pinning mode.

You can set the [securityPolicy](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/80d35488c67d6a0b75cfc6854bed891f9427f21a/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h#L165) on an AFHTTPRequestOperation:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
operation.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

Your certificate must have the extension `cer` not `crt` and should be in DER format. Add it to your bundle. You can convert it to the correct format in a terminal with the following command:

`openssl x509 -in domain.crt -out domain.cer -outform der`

You should not include keys in your app bundle, only the certificate is required.

Comment: I see. However I saw people telling that we should use public key since the certificate can change...

Comment: By using the `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey` pinning mode, AFNetworking will extract the public key from the certificate. It then compares this public key against the key in the certificate sent by the server. This allows you to generate a new certificate on the server and existing versions of your app will continue to work.

Comment: Understood. I'm going to try it. Thank you

Comment: What happens if the public key can't be extracted? Is that an encoding problem? @DavidCaunt

Comment: I get an error when it tries to look at the pinned certificates: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: allowedCertificate'`. I have tried every type of format with the .cer file to no avail...

Comment: `key` files are the _private_ part of the key pair. These should never, ever be published to the world.

Comment: I have done this and added my file in project but even if I use wrong certificate it send a request to server.

Comment: Hi David, some comment and entry speak to "allowInvalidCertificates = YES;". i am not sure this line. This is required or not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AFN these days, so probably best to open an issue on their GitHub project or support channels as appropriate, sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 4):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

/**** SSL Pinning ****/
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[self alloc] init];
securityPolicy.SSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModePublicKey;
[manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
/**** SSL Pinning ****/

[manager GET:WEBSITE_URL parameters:params
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary* responseObject) {
    //..... beautiful code here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //..... beautiful code here
}];
```

Hope this help

Check the link [here:](http://www.dodyrw.com/ssl-pinning-with-afnetworking-2/)
Also, refer [AFNetworking Documents](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFSecurityPolicy.html#overview)

Comment: Thank you that's quite helpful. Your links show how to pin a certificate but should I do the same to "pin" a public key ?