# SSL Pinning with AFNetworking 2.0 allowing POST requests regardless of cert file used

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ssl, ios7, afnetworking

We are using DigiCert as our CA.  We have made the .cer file with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in WEBSITE.crt -outform der -out WEBSITE.cer
```

which SHOULD work but the issue is that not only will that cer work but any file we put into the code will work. We have even tested blank .cer files and that works as well.  By work I mean we are able to make a post request to the server regardless of what .cer file is used.  Obviously we would like it to fail if something other than our signed cert is used.

Our origin is set at Cloudflare which then routes to an Amazon load balancer which has our certificates installed onto it.

I'm using Charles Proxy to MITM myself and I can do it with or without the cert in the iOS app.

We are using the latest release of `AFNetworking` to do the SSL pinning.  I subclassed `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` and added the following method:

```
+ (AFSecurityPolicy*) siteSecurityPolicy
{
    /**** SSL Pinning ****/
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WEBSITE" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO];
    [securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:@[certData]];
    [securityPolicy setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
   /**** SSL Pinning ****/

    return securityPolicy;
}
```

My code to make the post is as follows:

```
websiteRequestOperationManager *manager = [websiteRequestOperationManager manager];

/**** SSL Pinning ****/
[manager setSecurityPolicy:[websiteRequestOperationManager siteSecurityPolicy]];
/**** SSL Pinning ****/

[manager GET:WEBSITE_URL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary* responseObject) {
    //code
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //code
}];
```

What critical step have we missed?

I should also mention that I NSLog'd:

```
[manager.securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates count]
```

and received a 1.

Comment: Doesn't your goal (use any cert to POST) effectively break pinning? It seems to me you would only want to use the one true certificate or public key on the connection. Here's one of the past questions on `AFNetworking` and pinning: [AFNetworking pin public key for a trusted certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615144/afnetworking-pin-public-key-for-a-trusted-certificate).

Comment: Sorry I think I need to rephrase my question.  The GOAL is to use only our signed cert.  What's happening is it doesn't matter what cert file we use, it allows a post.  So the the process to match the server's cert to cert in the app isn't happening.

Comment: Where do I download `*.cer.pem` files for Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the case for me as well, using AFNetworking 2.3.1. AFNetworking 2.1.0 does not have this problem, however the pinning there breaks on iOS 8 beta 5.